# Type conversion error with Generic Interface

Tags: vb.net, interface

I'm trying to use interfaces for my Entities and Repositories but I can't seem to overcome a type conversion error. I have simplified the code to the basic minimum to reproduce this error.

```
'The entity interface
Public Interface IEntity
    Property ID As Int32
End Interface

'A base class for new entities
Public MustInherit Class EntityBase
    Implements IEntity

    Public Property ID As Integer Implements IEntity.ID
End Class

'The repository interface
Public Interface IRepository(Of IEntity)
    Function Load(ID As Int32) As IEntity
End Interface

'The base class for the repository
Public Class RepositoryBase(Of IEntity)
    Implements IRepository(Of IEntity)

    Public Overridable Function Load(ID As Integer) As IEntity Implements IRepository(Of IEntity).Load
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class

'An object using the entities base class
Public Class Person
    Inherits EntityBase

    Property Name As String
End Class

'An object using the repository base class
Public Class PersonRepository
    Inherits RepositoryBase(Of Person)

    Public Overrides Function Load(ID As Integer) As Person
        Dim myPerson As New Person
        'Do stuff for loading a Person
        Return myPerson
    End Function
End Class

'And here is some code to execute this all
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim PersonRepo As New PersonRepository
        Dim TestWithType As IRepository(Of IEntity)
        TestWithType = PersonRepo '<-- error goes here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Intellisense doesn't give any error. The error only pops up when executing the code. The exact error is in Dutch:

> Kan een object van het type Generic_Interface_test.PersonRepository
> niet converteren naar het type
> Generic_Interface_test.IRepository`1[Generic_Interface_test.IEntity].

So the `PersonRepository` cannot be converted to an `IRepository` type. But the `PersonRepository` class is based on the `RepositoryBase` which implements the `IRepository` interface.

What am I doing wrong here? In my final solution I want to drop my repositories into a dictionary but that seems impossible due to this error.

**Update 1**: The problem seems to be in the `IEntity` part. `IRepository(Of IEntity)` != `IRepository(Of Person)` while `Person` = `IEntity`.
Is there any way to create a list like `List(Of IRepository(Of IEntity))` that actually works?

**Update 2**: I like the animal example of Tim so I will try to explain my question with animals.

Assume I have an interface `IAnimal` that I will use in another interface `IRepository(Of IAnimal)`. For this type I will create a list `Animals = List(Of IRepository(Of IAnimal))` where I can store repositories for all animals. Now I will create a class `Lion` based on the `IAnimal` interface and create a repository `LionRepo` based on `IRepository(Of Lion)`. When I try to store `LionRepo` into `Animals` it fails because it expects `IRepository(Of IAnimal)` while my `LionRepo` is actually `IRepository(Of Lion)`. But since `Lion` is based on `IAnimal` shouldn't this suppose to be working?

Comment: @TimSchmelter When i create the `IAnimal` interface and use that for the classes `Lion` and `Giraf` I can actually create a `List(Of IAnimal)` and add both classes in there. So I don't see the problem there. I don't really try to convert the types. I want to add 2 objects with the same interface to a list of that interface.

Comment: What I actually want to do is create `List(Of IRepository(Of IEntity))` and add all objects that are based on `IRepository(Of IEntity)` in there. My object is actually defined as `IRepository(Of Person)` and Person is based on `IEntity`. But that's probably one type too deep.